# How to tell if two strings of any length are anagrams using bash, awk or any using command or script?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

The string or word can be of any length.

Eg "William Shakespeare" = "I am a weakish speller"  both are anagrams

E.g.  "Madam Curie" = "Radium came"

Comment: Am I wrong, or _(1)_ spa ce s don't count and _(2)_ caPiTalization doesn't count?

Comment: simple algorithm:
translate to lowercase, order all letters alphabetically, remove non-alphabetic characters, then compare the two strings. if they are equal, then they are anagrams

Comment: You might wanna look into this ['an' - very fast anagram generator](http://fatphil.org/words/an.html) for more complex cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
# function to cleanup a given argument by doing this:
# 1. Remove all alphanumerics
# 2. Convert to all lowercasing all characters 
# 3. Sorting all characters
# 4. Stripping all newlines 
prep() {
   fold -w1 <<< "${1//[^[:alnum:]]/}" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort | tr -d '\n'
}

# function to check if given 2 arguments are anagrams
isAnagram() {
   a=$(prep "$1")
   b=$(prep "$2")
   [[ $a = $b ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no";
}
```

To call them use:

```
isAnagram "William Shakespeare" "I am a weakish speller"
yes

isAnagram "Madam Curie" "Radium came"
yes

isAnagram "cat" "act"
yes

isAnagram "cat" "cot"
no
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava what is this <<< operator for ?

Comment: `<<<` is bash syntax for here-string. This feeds in given string as input to the command in use.

Comment: Can't just a single <  be used ?

Comment: Single `<` is used for having a file as input but `<<<` is used for having a string as input. Check `man bash` and search for `Here Strings`

Comment: thanks anubhava , I am also not able to understand this part   "${1//[^[:alnum:]]/}"  .. can you help please ? is it an operator ?

Comment: `"${1//[^[:alnum:]]/}"` removes all non-alphanumeric characters from `$1`

Comment: but how does it work ? do you have any reference doc which I can read to understand the syntax

Comment: Once again checking `man bash` will have reference of this. You may also go through a `bash` tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Easy with *Python*:

***anagram.py*** script:

```
import sys

s1 = sys.argv[1]
s2 = sys.argv[2]
fmt = '"{:s}" and "{:s}" are{:s} anargams'

if sorted(s1.lower().translate(None,' \n\r\t')) == sorted(s2.lower().translate(None,' \n\r\t')):
    print(fmt.format(s1, s2, ''))
else:
    print(fmt.format(s1, s2, ' NOT'))
```

Usage:

```
python anagrams.py "William Shakespeare" "I am a weakish speller"
```

The output:

```
"William Shakespeare" and "I am a weakish speller" are anargams
```

---

```
python anagrams.py "William Shakespeare" "William Hopkins"
```

The output:

```
"William Shakespeare" and "William Hopkins" are NOT anargams
```

Answer (score 0):

an awk solution looks not so compact like others, but slightly different:

```
awk -v s1="William Shakespeare" -v s2="I am a weakish speller" '    
function chkTxt(s) {
    split(tolower(s), arr, //)
    asort(arr)
    result=""
    for(i=1;i<=length(arr);i++)
        result = result""arr[i]
    return result
}

BEGIN{
    x=gsub(/[[:blank:]]/,"",s1)
    y=gsub(/[[:blank:]]/,"",s2)

    if (x+y==0 || (x&&y)) {
        print chkTxt(s1)==chkTxt(s2)? "True":"False"
        exit
    }
    print "False"
}'
```

here you pass the two string variable to `s1` and `s2`.

**Note** For space/blank checking, I noticed that your example doesn't restrict the count of the spaces, however, it seems that if there were spaces, two strings must have at least one spaces. Like `foo bar` and `f o o ba r` are anagrams. However `foobar` and `barf o o` are not.

The above codes do the check.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

#set -x

i=0
for letter in {A..Z}
do
alphabet[$i]="$letter"
((i++))
done

i=0
for digits in {0..25}
do
array[$i]=0
((i++))
done

read -p "Enter first word: " word1
read -p "Enter second word: " word2

while read -n 1 letter
do

if [ -z "$letter" ]
then continue
fi
for b in "${!alphabet[@]}"
do
if [ "$letter" = "${alphabet[$b]}" ]
then
((array[$b]+=1))
break
fi
done
done < <(echo "${word1^^}")

while read -n 1 letter
do
if [ -z "$letter" ]
then continue
fi
for b in "${!alphabet[@]}"
do
if [ "$letter" = "${alphabet[$b]}" ]
then
((array[$b]-=1))
break
fi
done
done < <(echo "${word2^^}")

echo -n "Words are "
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
if [ "$element" -ne 0 ]
then echo -n "not "
fi
done

echo "anagrams"

echo
exit
```

And in functions

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

i=0
for letter in {A..Z}
do
alphabet[$i]="$letter"
((i++))
done


read_word(){
local array=()
local i=0
for digits in {0..25}
do
array[$i]=0
((i++))
done
local sentence="$1"
while read -n 1 letter
do
if [ -z "$letter" ]
then continue
fi
for b in "${!alphabet[@]}"
do 
if [ "$letter" = "${alphabet[$b]}" ]
then
((array[$b]+=1))
break
fi
done
done < <(echo "${sentence^^}")
echo "${array[@]}"
}
 
equal_array(){
if [ "$1" = "$2" ]
then echo "anagrams"
else echo " not anagrams"
fi
}
 
read -p "Enter first word: " word1
read -p "Enter second word: " word2

word1=($(read_word "$word1"))
word2=($(read_word "$word2"))

equal_array "${word1[*]}" "${word2[*]}"

exit
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).